# Kubernetes: mount: special device does not exist when attaching AWS EBS volume

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, kubernetes, amazon-ebs

dear Kubernetes guru's!

I have spinned kube 1.4.1 cluster on manually created AWS hosts using 'contrib' Ansible playbook (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible).

My problem is that Kube doesn't attach EBS drives to minion hosts. If I define the pod as follows:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1 
kind: Deployment 
metadata:
  name: kafka1
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka1
        image: daniilyar/kafka
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092 
          name: clientconnct
          protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /kafka
          name: storage
      volumes:
      - name: storage
        awsElasticBlockStore:
          volumeID: vol-56676d83
          fsType: ext4
```

I get the following error in kubelet.log:

```
Mounting arguments: /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/vol-56676d83 /var/lib/kubelet/pods/db213783-9477-11e6-8aa9-12f3d1cdf81a/volumes/kubernetes.io~aws-ebs/storage  [bind]
Output: mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/vol-56676d83 does not exist
```

EBS volume keeps being in 'Available' state during that, so I am sure that Kube **doesn't attach** volume to host at all and so, **doesn't mount** it.
I am 100% sure that this is a Kubernetes itself issue and not the permissioning issue because I can mount the same volume manually from within this minion to this minion just fine:

```
$ aws ec2 --region us-east-1 attach-volume --volume-id vol-56676d83 --instance-id $(wget -q -O - http://instance-data/latest/meta-data/instance-id) --device /dev/sdc
{
    "AttachTime": "2016-10-18T15:02:41.672Z", 
    "InstanceId": "i-603cfb50", 
    "VolumeId": "vol-56676d83", 
    "State": "attaching", 
    "Device": "/dev/sdc"
}
```

Googling, hacking and trying older K8 versions didn't help me to solve this. 
Could anyone please point me on what else could I do to understand the problem so I can fix it? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

Nobody helped me at K8 Slack channels, so after a day of pulling my hair off I found the solution by myself:

To get the K8 cluster installed by 'contrib' Ansible playbook (https://github.com/kubernetes/contrib/tree/master/ansible) mounting EBS volumes properly, except for IAM roles setup, you need to add the **--cloud-provider=aws** flag to your existing cluster: all kubelets, the apiserver, and the controller manager.

Without **--cloud-provider=aws** flag Kubernetes will give you an unfriendly 'mount: special device xxx does not exist' error instead of real cause.

Comment: I have the same issue as well. How can I add the flag? Is there a specific config file I should edit?

Comment: @JiashenCao , it can be changed in /etc K8 config files, for example, on Debian for kubelet it is /etc/sysconfig/kubelet, and so on..

Answer (score 2):

With a kubeadm configuration, configuration is defined in:
`/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml` and 
`/var/lib/kubelet/kubeadm-flags.env`

My issue that I had was that the environmental variables were defined on the master node in `kubeadm-flags.env` but not in the second node.

To resolve this manually I added the `--cloud-provider=aws` tag to the `kubeadm-flags.env` and restarted the services, which resolved the issue:
`systemctl daemon-reload && systemctl restart kubelet`

Comment: same issue for me. added --cloud-provider flag on the master but not the worker