# Kubernetes cannot attach AWS EBS as volume. Probably due to cloud provider issue

Tags: kubernetes

I hava a kubernetes cluster up running on AWS. Now when I'm trying to attach a AWS EBS as a volume to a pod, I got a "special device does not exist" problem.

> Output: mount: special device /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/vol-xxxxxxx does not exist

I did some research and found that the correct AWS EBS device path should be like this format:

> /var/lib/kubelet/plugins/kubernetes.io/aws-ebs/mounts/aws/us-west-2a/vol-xxxxxxxx

My doubt is that it might because I set up the Kubernetes cluster according to this [tutorial](http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/kubeadm/) and did not set the cloud provider, and therefore the AWS device "does not exit". I wonder if my doubt is correct, and if yes, how to set the cloud provider after the cluster is already up running.

Comment: Can you specify what version you used? Also, was your AWS deployment made using kops?

Comment: See link to my resolution for kubeadm:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/60325491/10843666

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the cloud provider to properly mount an EBS volume. To do that after the fact set `--cloud-provider=aws` in the following services:

- controller-manager
- apiserver
- kubelet

Restart everything and try mounting again.

An example pod which mounts an EBS volume explicitly may look like this:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: test-ebs
spec:
  containers:
  - image: gcr.io/google_containers/test-webserver
    name: test-container
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: /test-ebs
      name: test-volume
  volumes:
  - name: test-volume
    # This AWS EBS volume must already exist.
    awsElasticBlockStore:
      volumeID: <volume-id>
      fsType: ext4
```

Answer (score 0):

The Kubernetes version is an important factor here. The EBS mounts was experimental in 1.2.x, I tried it then but without success. In the last releases I never tried it again but be sure to check your IAM roles on the k8s vm's to make sure they have the rights to provision EBS disks.